# SQL Data type for monetary values with up to 15 decimal places

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sqldatatypes

I have a need to store and do some basic calculations (mostly multiplication) on monetary values like `£0.00005756`, `£0.01`, `£0.000000000000123`, etc. The maximum number of decimal places is going to be 15 but there could be fairly large numbers on the other side too. If there's more than a `0` on the left side it's unlikely that more than 2 decimal places would be utilised but it is possible. The numbers I have had trouble with are when it goes above 2 decimal places.

I created a test table and inserted some basic data. Unfortunately it can't seem to store really small numbers.

Note: I created the `money2` column as `[decimal](18, 4)` column as this seems to be recommended when I've researched what to use for monetary values. However, I need 15 decimal places, which is why `money1` exists.

Table creation:

```
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MoneyTest](
        [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [money1] [decimal](18, 15) NULL,
        [money2] [decimal](18, 4) NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_uMoneyTest] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO

insert into moneytest 
(money1, money2) values
(£0.01,£0.01)

insert into moneytest 
(money1, money2) values
(£0.000000000000123,£0.000000000000123)

insert into moneytest 
(money1, money2) values
(£0.00005756,£0.00005756)
```

`select * from moneytest` returns the following results:

```
id  money1              money2
7   0.010000000000000   0.0100
8   0.000000000000000   0.0000
9   0.000100000000000   0.0001
```

I was expecting these results though:

```
id  money1              money2
7   0.010000000000000   0.0100
8   0.000000000000123   0.0000
9   0.000575600000000   0.0001
```

In particular, row id 9 seems to be rounding up to a 1 (at decimal point 4) instead of showing the actual figure. I thought this only happened when using floating point columns that estimate numbers and that decimal was meant to be more accurate?

Is this just a datatype problem or is it something that I shouldn't be trying to resolve in the database at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the pound-sign.  It means that the values are being read as `money` -- which is not high enough precision.  So, you are losing decimal places.

Just remove the currency symbol:

```
insert into moneytest (money1, money2)
    values (0.000000000000123, 0.000000000000123);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1400f76a76da5fd4ee2b1bc5029382f2) is a db<>fiddle.